# exception to forwrding rule, DNS, Server 2008

Tags: dns, windows-server-2008-r2

We have our company domain servers located in the UK, and our office is in Ireland.
The domain is, let's say, 'domain.com'. 
Our connection to the UK office goes over VPN which is getting fully utilised.

I wonder if I can take some of the websites which end with 'domain.com' and which also work from outside of the LAN, like 'webmail.domain.com' and send them not over the VPN, but across the open internet.

I could have forwarder for every website we use on domain 'domain.com' I suppose, but if there is a possibility to put in an exception to the rule, it would be better.

Any ideas?

Lenks

Answer (score 0):

Oh my, the very first thing I tried today and which did not work for me, worked after I tried again:

1. create conditional forwarder for 'domain.com'
2. create conditional forwarder for 'webmail.domain.com'
3. restart DNS Server service
4. run  'ipconfig /flushdns' on the host PC